# Помощь в изменении кода функции покупки

Tags: xcode, swift3

В swift 2.1 такая функция покупки работала. Помогите переделать на swift 3.1

```
var listOfProducts = [SKProduct]()
var productoPurchase = SKProduct()

func buyProduct() {
print("buy " + productoPurchase.productIdentifier)
let pay = SKPayment(product: productoPurchase)
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay)
}
```

Xcode ругается на строки

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay)
```

И предлогает исправить на

```
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(pay)
```

Немного поискав нашел вариант исправления второй строки на

```
SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(pay)
```

https://codedump.io/share/GYuvWc0s4HMi/1/skpaymentqueuedefaultqueueaddpaymentpayment-crash-when-moving-between-vc-swift-2330

Answer (score 0):

`SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
.
.
.
let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)`

Вообще то надо [вот это](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2387/_index.html) хорошенечко проштудировать, если хотите все сделать правильно, обратите внимание, что там есть куски кода с пометками '*как не надо делать (Does not follow best practices..)*' и '*как надо делать (Follows best practices..)*'.
Ваш код не похож на последний тип.